# What's the role of だけの in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words, particle-だけ

> 彼らは工場を建設するだけの資金を持っている。

The translation on Jisho is: "They have enough capital to build a second factory."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

だけ of course mainly means "only", but it has other meanings. `clause + だけ` can mean "to the degree that ～".

[On JGram](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=dake), the following examples are relevant.

> - この本は読むだけの価値がある。
>     This book is certainly worth reading.
>     (lit. "This book has the value to the extent you read")
> - 日本語がこれだけ書ければとてもすばらしいと思います。
>     I think it's great that you can write Japanese like this. (or: this much, to this extent)

Comment: Thank you! But I have a doubt about the last sentence, I can't understand this reflection: "書ければ". Could you explain me?

Comment: It's a [conditional form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/conditional) of the [potential form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential) of the verb 書く. 書く (write) → 書ける (can write) → 書ければ (if ... can write).

Answer (score 2):

(wanted to just leave a comment, but I don't have enough points or something...)

I think it's a typo. Should be: これだけ書けばとても、、、

Edit --

あら！The 書ければ form is indeed correct. 書く=to write, 書ける=is able to write, 書ければ= if __ were able to write. 間違いました！m(_ _)m

Comment: 「日本語がこれだけ書ければ・書けたら・書けるなら」←おかしくないと思いますけど・・・？「書け(る)」は potential form 可能形ですよね・・・訳にも you **can** write って書いてありますし・・「これだけ書けば・書いたら」とはちょっと意味が違ってきますよね・・